# How to trim a series of string objects in python?

Tags: python, pandas, strip

is there any way to trim a series of string objects with out using for loop. I can do this element by element. I have a series `a`

```
print a
0    ﻿164
1     164
2     164
3     164
4     164
5     164
```

now I have to remove space at the start of each " 164"s.
 `a.strip()` results in `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'`
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you please show us the strings you want to get in this specific example?

Comment: I want to convert them into int type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well nothing wrong with your data or code, but do check the data thoroughly, even if one row doesn't have the right data, and you are trying to convert a series's particular columns type for a given range yet the entire series is being considered and thus your problem..

Reduce the test set and check for a couple of rows, it should just work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.strip` to remove the spaces:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['164', ' 164', '    164']})
for item in df.a:
    print (len(item))
3
4
7
In [11]:

df.a = df.a.str.strip(' ')
for item in df.a:
    print (len(item))
3
3
3
```

To convert to ints do this:

```
In [20]:

df.a = df.a.astype(int)
df.dtypes

Out[20]:
a    int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: thats the 1st thing I have tried. Something is wrong with the data. I have to break the data in multiple files than may be I will be able to see whats the problem. Thanks for the ans

Comment: @sau what version of pandas are you using `pd.version.version` will output the version if you don't immediately know

Comment: pandas version 0.10.1

Comment: @sau not sure what the problem, can you upgrade to 0.13?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used pandas, but if I understand correctly you might be wanting to do something like this.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'a': ['164', ' 165']})
for index, row in df.iterrows():  
    print int(row['a'])
```

Sorry if I'm off-topic :-)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to convert it to an int, how about just `df[0].astype(int)`?

```
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame([' 164', '164', '164 ', '  164  '])

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
         0
0      164
1      164
2     164 
3    164  

[4 rows x 1 columns]

In [18]: df.dtypes
Out[18]: 
0    object
dtype: object

In [19]: df[0] = df[0].astype(int)

In [20]: df.dtypes
Out[20]: 
0    int64
dtype: object

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
     0
0  164
1  164
2  164
3  164

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: I am looking into string because astype(int) not working so I thought something is wrong in the data itself which I have not figured out yet.

Answer (score 1):

You shall use a regular expression :

```
import re

trim_function = lambda x : re.findall("^\s*(.*?)\s*$",str(x))[0]
```

To explain a bit :

- The character `^` represents the beginning of the string, and `$` is the end of your string ; so that your expression will find exactly 1 match.
- `\s` represents any whitespace character. So `\s*` is any sequence (even empty) of whitespaces.
- `.*?` is any sequence of any character. I could not explain precisely why, but the `?` sign let this experrsion be less *greedy* than `\s*` so that the whitespaces will be counted outside the parenthesis.
- Finally, the parethesis `(...)` means that you are interseted in the substring(s) inside of them : the expression trimmed.

As `re.findall` provides a list of matching substrings, we have to select the first element.

Now, for a DataFrame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([' 164', '164', '164 ', '  164  '])
df.applymap(trim_function)
```

For a Series

```
df = pd.Series([' 164', '164', '164 ', '  164  '])
df.apply(trim_function)
```

For an Index

```
df = pd.Index([' 164', '164', '164 ', '  164  '])
df.map(trim_function)
```

*edit* : Forgot : if you don't want to remove spaces at the end of each string, simply use the pattern `"^\s*(.*?)"`.